# Android - menu button opens system active apps

Tags: android

I've got a Samsung tablet SM-T560 on which when pressing the touch 'menu' key (next to the hardware 'home' button) opens the system menu for 'Active apps' where you can close or navigate to a previously opened app.

How can i override this functionality?I want to disable showing active apps upon this menu button click.

Answer (score 1):

you need to override the menu button using the `onKeyDown(int, KeyEvent)` method in your activity. The following code snippet should be a good start for you:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent event) {

    switch(keycode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
            //Your functionality here
            return true;

    }

return super.onKeyDown(keycode, event);

}
```

Comment: This one doesn't work , tried already. In fact i tried logging the 'keycode' and when clicking the menu button , the onKeyDown method is not triggered at all.

But generally this should be the solution as i knew before even posting.

Comment: I see, this information would've been good in your question. i'll look into it when I get a chance.

Comment: Maybe i was too hasty asking a question.Anyway i have found an [open issues](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159795) which has given me an insight.I guess i'll have to wait.

Comment: We managed to not listen to the key but rather if our app is being overlayed. If you want I can look up the code.

Comment: Well it's a tablet that will work with this app only but they just want it disabled not to click it by mistake .. well clients ... :D 

I think it won't be necessary, thanks tho.